# Script Aborting in Edge (42) but Working in Chrome (74)

Tags: javascript

Problem: Restated
The issue is/was and remains real and vexing, but it is ultimately not a javascript coding syntax or routine error. At the end of consternation and trouble shooting, correctly seen and thus able to be defined, the problem is that in local file path I was using as my development test bed (ie. file:///C:/Users/GladHeart/restOfPath/myFileWithScripts.html), allowed some scripts to work in Edge BUT, those which containing logic and sorts using sessionStorage and localStorage referencing aborted the scripts. [See answer.]

Comment: It's just window.onload, Actually you can even leave the window off and just use `onload = function(){/* all DOM code should be here */ }`. Well, this may be the only time I use this style so I can use multiple loads `addEventListener('load', function(){ /* all DOM code should be here */ });`. Otherwise I prefer the overwrite style, so I don't have to remove Events.

Comment: I am using a multi-onload approach. Using the code you suggested for that, I can not seem to make work. I cleaned up my initial code by removing window from window.sessionStorage.setItem(declareMenu); I also played with multiple combinations of window.document / window. / document. /etc. all to no avail. Please I will paste your code as I tried to use it and ask for the correct syntax in making it work to return a value in both Edge and Chrome to the last alert. I have provided more information, by edited adding to my initial question. Is asking for a CodePen correction of my work amenable?

Comment: Use external JavaScript in your `<head><script type='text/javascript' src='folder/file.js'></script></head>`.

Comment: Truly, thanks @StackSlave for your patient interest. I did try your pre-HTML5 suggestion with the hope you offered. Please check the totally minimized, copy and paste, working html example (css and javascript embedded for compactness and direct one page loading) that I have placed as a functioning demonstration in my completely re-edited question, albeit the topic remains unchanged.

Comment: Make everything happen onload.

Answer (score 0):

The stated problem is an Edge security implementation issue. And at that, only local to my computer (not accessing a production web URL) when I was developing using a local template path of file:///C:/Users/GladHeart/restOfPath/myFileWithScripts.html. Some scripts worked BUT, the scripts that I was mainly using contained logic and sorts using sessionStorage and localStorage. It turns they were aborting locally in Edge due to a 'ServiceWorker' failure to access.........gotta love Microsoft's finally trying to pay attention to security issues. Anyway, after a week of believing it was my coding syntax or something straight forward, I have left it as it is in the universe of wasted effort. I did briefly, after discovering the basis of the problem, try some Google search recommended solutions to address such an error. They suggested turning on IPV6 (unfortunately my router is IPV4); and, also addressing the situation by adding my local IP to trusted sites (which I followed). My solution, short of sidetracking myself after breaking through, is, as it stands, to just use Chrome for local development; and then, test both Chrome and Edge by upload to my website when I feel the content is robust and ready for final testing.